# How can I append an extension to files that don't already have one?

Tags: unix, batch-file, cron, grep, find

I have a cron that appends `.txt` to each file in a directory.

```
find /path/to/directory -type f -exec mv '{}' '{}'.txt \;
```

Unfortunately it **keeps** appending `.txt` even if it already has it!

My directory looks like this now...

```
file1.txt.txt.txt.txt.txt.txt.txt.txt.txt
file2.txt.txt.txt.txt.txt.txt.txt.txt.txt
```

What do you recommend?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to modify your `find` command to exclude files with extensions.

```
find /path/to/files ! -name "*.*" -type f -exec mv '{}' '{}'.txt \;
```

However, this would also mean it would ignore files like:

```
i.am.a.file.with.no.extension
```

So if you have files like the above then it's better to use `regex` option to index the `.` at `$`.

Comment: Thanks! Any tips to rename all of my multiple `.txt.txt` extensions back to normal? ;)

Comment: You can do something like `find . -name "*.txt.txt" -type f -exec rename 's/.txt$//' {} \;` to normalize them back to having single `.txt` extension.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I don't have `rename` so I'll look around for another option.

Comment: Oh sorry about that, if you are using `bash` then you can do `find -name "*.txt.txt" -type f | while read f; do mv "$f" "${f%.txt}"; done`